# Passing dict with boolean values to function using double asterisk

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have something like this:

```
def x(**kwargs):
    y(**kwargs)

def y(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

d = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': True,
  'c': 'Grace'
}
x(d)
```

The behavior I'm seeing, using a debugger, is that `kwargs` in `y()` is equal to this:

```
{
  'kwargs': {
    'a': 1,
    'c': 'Grace'
  }
}
```

My obviously mistaken understanding of the double asterisk is that it is supposed to pack and unpack a dictionary of key value pairs, allowing you to pass dictionaries into methods as keyword arguments. However, two things confuse me:

- Why is the packing nesting the dictionary under a `kwargs` key?
- Why is the boolean being dropped?

I'd ideally like to avoid both of these behaviors, but am clearly missing something about how the particulars of this double asterisk behavior works.

Comment: check your problem again... You should be getting TypeError: x() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given.

Comment: I don't see your behaviour in 3.5. Firstly I get an error `x() takes 0 positional arguments`, so changing to `x(**d)` doesn't nest under `kwargs`, obviously `x(kwargs=d)` gives the nested dict but at no time does the `'b'` disappear.

Comment: This should be closed/deleted: I had serious confusion when I was debugging my situation, and this was made in too much haste. Apologies and thanks to everyone who looked at it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the behaviour of your code was, but for me it throws an error. We can get the same error with a smaller example:

```
def x(**kwargs):
    pass

d = {"a": 1, "b": 2}

x(d)
```

throws:

```
TypeError: x() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

The problem is simply that this isn't how the `**` syntax works. `def x(**kwargs)` denotes a function that can take an arbitrary number of **named variables**, like so:

```
def x(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

x(a = 1, b = 2)
```

prints

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

You however are passing it the object `d`, in other words you are passing the function **one positional variable** -- no named variables. Hence the exception.

The other distinct syntactical use of `**` is for unpacking a dictionary of kwargs into a function that has been defined in the usual way to accept named arguments, for example:

```
def f(a, b):
    print(a, b)

d = {"a": 1, "b": 2}

f(**d)
```

prints

```
1 2
```

To get fully to grips with this you should check out the tutorial in the Python docs, here:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions